# Can I get a stdout of basic MySQL commands in BASH?

Tags: mysql, bash

Can I get a stdout of basic MySQL commands in BASH? show, describe for starters. I'm troubleshooting a problem with several databases and I want to compare them with increasing specificity. The dump is just too much information.

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit more? "getting a stdout" is confusing. Are you wanting to get the output of the `mysql` data into a bash variable?

Comment: I think the answers get the gist of my intent--gather a few different ways to quickly get different "looks", or filters of the database from the command line. Thanks to these I just stumbled on one I can't believe if forgot, [mysqlshow](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlshow.html)

Answer (score 5):

```
echo "command" | mysql -u username -ppassword -h host database_name
```

not only basic command but full SQL can be run this way

Comment: No space between `-p` and `password`.

Comment: This is exactly what `mysql -e` is for. Why would you ever want to do `echo "foobar" | mysql` over `mysql -e "foobar"`?

Comment: Since these two (`mysql -e "foobar"` and `echo "foobar" | mysql"`) are both valid answer (and there is still third valid answer using `mysql < foobar.sql `), I don't think there is anything wrong with this answer.

Comment: @Dhchen. Well defended ;) The -e option is for one command only?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can but there are too useful options in mysqldump that can help you

The first option is dumping the structure only without any data by adding the -d option

```
mysqldump -d -h host -u username -p databasename > dumpfile.sql
```

The other great option is --where, and here is the description from the manual :

```
 --where="where-condition", -w "where-condition"

          Dump only records selected by the given WHERE condition. Note that
          quotes around the condition are mandatory if it contains spaces or
          characters that are special to your command interpreter.

          Examples:

          "--where=user=’jimf’"
          "-wuserid>1"
          "-wuserid<1"
```

For more info check it on the mysqldump man page : http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/mysqldump1.html